# Loop through ado.net sql select to add more rows to datatable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, c#-4.0, ado.net

I currently have a working query for the first element in the array of ID's as seen below. What I need to do is add a for loop so I rerun the query for every element in the array and add each new row to the datatable but I am not sure how I do this? Unless there is a way I can include all ID's of my array in the where clause so I retrieve all rows through first run.

PID[] is a string array and could have anywhere from 1 to 5 elements that are random ID's.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
        for loop here?

        string firstQuery = "select * from Property p " +
                            "where p.id in (@pID)";

        connString.Open();

        SqlCommand selectAll = new SqlCommand(firstQuery, connString);
        selectAll.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pID", PID[0]);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = selectAll;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        connString.Close();
        DataTable table = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: In almost all cases when you think you have to run a query inside a loop, you are mistaken.  gzaxx seems to have a good answer for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can include all ids in one parameter and get results that match them:

```
var parameters = new string[PID.Length];
var selectAll = new SqlCommand();

for (int i = 0; i < PID.Length; i++)
{
    parameters[i] = string.Format("@Age{0}", i);
    selectAll .Parameters.AddWithValue(parameters[i], PID[i]);
}

selectAll.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * from Property p WHERE p.id IN ({0})", string.Join(", ", parameters));
selectAll.Connection = connString;

connString.Open();

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = selectAll;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds);

connString.Close();
DataTable table = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: I am having trouble getting pids to work as a parameter but will keep you posted

Comment: Can you write what troubles do you have?

Comment: Your code fails when filling the dataset. I am gessing its related to the quotes or commas but cant seem to figure out which yet

Comment: In result string there should be only ids with , as separator, nothing else. Please show me your `pids` string just before you pass it to command

Comment: Everything looks fine :/. Is your `p.id` of type `nvarchar(max)` or `int`?

Comment: int and it works fine when i do one alone as mentioned in the question

Comment: I thought maybe it was related to the single quotes because in sql it would be: in ('86337','210597','85359')

Comment: Then there is no way why this should not work! Try executing that query "select * from Property p where p.id in (86337,210597,85359)" in SQL server management studio, maybe there is some other error I just can't see.

Comment: Heres my exception Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '86337,210597,85359' to data type int. in sql it is int!?

Comment: Ah `AddWithValue` detects types and converts it to nvarchar, my bad! Changed code above, please see if it works.

Comment: OK that got a lot more complicated :) but it looks like its working

Comment: Funny thing that if we would not use `Parameters` (and got eternal flame from SO users) then it would be super easy :). Anyway glad it worked :)

Comment: The alternative being a concatenated string in the where im assuming?

Comment: Yep. Create full command text without using `Parameters` like: `"SELECT * from Property p WHERE p.id IN ({0})", string.Join(", ", PID)` but it is not recommended approach.

Comment: Oh wow much easier lol.  Yeah my senior wont let us not use parameters due to possibility of sql injection attacks